# Could not parse the remainder: '[1]' from 'i[1]' no Django

Tags: python-3.x, django, template

Estou tentando fazer uma verificação para modificar o componente do bootstrap conforme o id de status, mas ele me retorna este erro:

> Could not parse the remainder: '[1]' from 'i[1]' no Django

O trecho de código que dá erro é esse que segue:

```
{%for i in cli %}
    {% for x in i %}
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <h5 class="list-group-item row">
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                {{ x.nome }} {{ x.sobrenome }}
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                {{ x.email }}
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                {% if {{ i.1 }} == 1 %}
                <a href="/desativa_cliente/{{ x.cpf }}">
                    <span class = "glyphicon glyphicon-remove pull-right"></span>
                </a>
                {% elif {{ i.1 }} == 2 %}
                    <a href="/desativa_cliente/{{ x.cpf }}">
                        <span class = "glyphicon glyphicon-repeat pull-right"></span>
                    </a>
                {% elif {{ i.1 }} == 2 %}
                    <a href="/desativa_cliente/{{ x.cpf }}">
                        <span class = "glyphicon glyphicon-repeat pull-right"></span>
                    </a>
                {% endif %}
                <a href="/clientes/edita_cliente/{{ x.cpf }}/">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit pull-right" style="margin-left:10px;"></span>
                </a>
            </div>
        </h5>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Qual é o tipo de `i`? Dentro de um template do Django, `i.1` seria o mesmo que `i[1]`, mas a menos que `i` seja uma lista isso não faz muito sentido... Além disso, dentro de um `{% ... %}` você pode acessar variáveis diretamente, não precisa [e até onde eu sei, nem pode] usar `{{ var }}`.